# Can I post XML data to a Restfull service

Tags: c#, wcf, winapi

I have an application that will be posting an XML object to me. 
Is it possible to create a Restful service (I'm assuming using Win API) to post the data to, or should I be using WCF services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with WebAPI by just reading the content stream from the request:

```
public XmlDocument ReadRawXml(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

You can call that in your WebAPI code.